# I receive cookies that were not set by my server

Tags: cookies

I run a commercial website and I make use of cookies. I log all user traffic and can often see cookies sent to me by the users browser that were not set by me. The rules state that a browser cannot send a cookie that was set by another domain. Perhaps javascript can set a cookie, but what is the point as my server will not look for any cookies other than those set by my PHP software.

As I often receive cyber attacks I will abort any requested page which contains any GET, POST or COOKIE data with variables I don't use and with any data that contains characters I would not use and if the string length of the variable is outside limits I set.

I'm worried some of my client base are not able to use the site due to this cookie issue. By looking at the User Agent info I see spiders are mostly responcible for my site aborting a requested page.

Does anyone understand this behaviour and perhaps know the point of sending cookies unknown to a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple places these could be coming from.

As you guessed, cookies can be set on the client side with JavaScript. They can also be set for a whole domain and all its subdomains, e.g., `yoursite.example.com` can set a cookie for `.example.com`, which would then be sent to *any* subdomain of example.com.

In either case, your server very well may not be the target for the cookies. Just as JavaScript can set a cookie (with `document.cookie`) it can also read from these cookies. This is one of the most widely supported ways to make data persist between pages in a browsing session; the fact that the data is sent to the server may just be an unintended side-effect. You see this a lot with things like analytics scripts or ad network tracking.

Generally these cookies are nothing to worry about. As long as you *always* validate your user input, you'll be fine.

If you are worried about cookies set from JavaScript overwriting *your* cookies, you can set a cookie as HTTP-only. Consult the [PHP docs on setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments. You say JavaScript can set a cookie but the pages of my web site contain minimal JavaScript and I certainly don't set any cookies in my JavaScript. As far as I am aware the user's browser after loading one of my pages would only contain the HTML/CSS/JavaScript that I have created. So how do I get cookies I didn't set? I'm puzzled! There are no ads on my page. Its just simple HTML/CSS with no content from any other sites linked in.